# How to model arbitrarily ordering items in database?

Tags: database, database-design

I accepted a new feature to re-order some items by using Drag-and-Drop UI and save the preference for each user to the database. What's the best way to do so?

After reading some questions on StackOverflow, I found this solution.

**Solution 1:** Use decimal numbers to indicate order

For example,

```
id     item     order
 1        a         1
 2        b         2
 3        c         3
 4        d         4
```

If I insert item 4 between item 1 and 2, the order becomes,

```
id     item     order
 1        a         1
 4        d         1.5
 2        b         2
 3        c         3
```

In this way, every new order = order[i-1] + order[i+1] / 2

If I need to save the preference for every user, then I need to another relationship table like this,

```
user_id     item_id     order
      1           1         1
      1           2         2
      1           3         3
      1           4         1.5
```

I need num_of_users * num_of_items records to save this preference.

However, there's a solution I can think of.

**Solution 2:** Save the order preference in a column in the User table

This is straightforward by adding a column in the User table to record the order. Each value would be parsed as an array of item_ids that ranked by the index of the array.

```
user_id .   item_order
      1       [1,4,2,3]
      2       [1,2,3,4]
```

Is there any limitation of this solution? Or is there any other ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, an explicit ordering deals with the presentation or some specific processing of data. Hence, it's a good idea to separate entities of theirs presentation/processing. For example

```
users
-----
user_id (PK)
user_login
...

user_lists
----------
list_id, user_id (PK)
item_index
```

`item_index` can be a simply integer value :

- ordered continuously (1,2...N): `DELETE/INSERT` of the whole list are normally required to change the order
- ordered discretely with some seed (10,20...N): you can insert new items without reordering the whole list

Another reason to separate entity data and lists: reordering lists should be done in transaction that may lead to row/table locks. In case of separated tables only data in list table is impacted.